# How can we use Triggers to insert records for particular column values that are present in main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

**This is my main table(Reference)**

```
    CREATE TABLE [ptref].[EarningDecode](
    [CountryGroupingCd] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [EarningsCd] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [EarningsDesc] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [CreateUserID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDttm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateUserId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDttm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EarningDecode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CountryGroupingCd] ASC,
    [EarningsCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

There is another table

```
CREATE TABLE [rt].[AdditionalPaymentsRealTime](
    [PeopleKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PersonnelNbr] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [SAPStartDt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SAPEndDt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EarningsCd] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [FlatAmountPaymentAmt] [decimal](13, 2) NULL,
    [CurrencyCd] [char](5) NULL,
    [PaymentFrequencyCd] [char](3) NULL,
    [FrequencyCountNbr] [decimal](3, 0) NULL,
    [AdditionalPaymentsNbr] [decimal](7, 2) NULL,
    [UnitCd] [char](3) NULL,
    [PayrollWageTypeInd] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [RecordTypeInd] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [MRDRExpiryDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [SAPChangeDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [SAPUpdateUserNm] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DocumentCreateDttm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IDOCId] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [IDOCCounter] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [CreateUserID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDttm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateUserId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDttm] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AdditionalPaymentsRealTime] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [PeopleKey] ASC,
    [PersonnelNbr] ASC,
    [SAPStartDt] ASC,
    [SAPEndDt] ASC,
    [EarningsCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The requirement here is in rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime only records where EarningsCd in (Select distinct EarningsCd from ptref.EarningDecode) should be inserted and for invalid values an error should be thrown.

I came up with the below query, but it doesn't seem like working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgrr
ON rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON ;
Declare @EarningsCdnew char(4)
Set @EarningsCdnew = (Select EarningsCd from rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime)
IF (NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT EarningsCd 
      FROM ptref.EarningDecode 
      WHERE EarningsCd = @EarningsCdnew))
ROLLBACK TRAN ;   
THROW 60000, 'Cannot process invalid EarningsCd', 1 ; 

END
```

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Why not use a Foreign Key Constraint?

Comment: The statement `Set @EarningsCdnew = (Select EarningsCd from rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime)` also *assumes* that the table `rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime` can only ever contain **one** row; I doubt this will be true.

Comment: Finally, having a `ROLLBACK` in the `TRIGGER` is a bad idea. Instead you should increase the severity of the `THROW` (to a minimum of `10`), and then the calling process will handle the error with a `ROLLBACK` and/or enter the external `CATCH`. Putting a `ROLLBACK` inside a `TRIGGER` generates additional errors.

Comment: [**Brent Ozar: The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers**](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Your throw is not within the same block as the THEN portion of the IF statement - you have no BEGIN / END for that. An INSTEAD-OF trigger puts the burden of actually moving the changes into the correct table(s) on the trigger writer - you have neglected that as well. And let's develop good habits. Use statement terminators ALWAYS - not just randomly.

Comment: Having a second look at your table, having a Primary Key made up of 5 columns seems like a significant design flaw. 2 columns for a PK *is* acceptable, but you need to ensure that both columns are in the other tables; which isn't always desirable. YOur table `AdditionalPaymentsRealTime` is missing the column `CountryGroupingCd` for your Foreign Key Constraint. Seems like you have some underlying design flaws you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than continue to post multiple more comments, I'm going to use an answer to explain the flaws you have here, including all those touched on by myself and others in the comments.

Firstly the point that myself and @Charlieface have made, and that your trigger is flawed in that it assumes a single row count. Specifically, that problem is on this line:

```sql
Set @EarningsCdnew = (Select EarningsCd from rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime)
```

This statement will only work *if* the objec (`rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime`) contains one or zero rows. If it doesn't then you're going to get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is because you can't assign the a **scalar** variable the value of many rows; it can only be assigned a scalar value.

Next, let's look at your `IF`, `ROLLBACK` and `THROW`. As [@Smor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798927/how-can-we-use-triggers-to-insert-records-for-particular-column-values-that-are#comment118079985_66798927) highlighted, firstly you're `THROW` is not inside your `IF`, which is a problem. This means that every *every* time the trigger is called (and the prior error doesn't occur) the error `'Cannot process invalid EarningsCd'` is going to be throw. If we add some better formatting, this is what your `IF` block really looks more like:

```sql
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT EarningsCd 
               FROM ptref.EarningDecode 
               WHERE EarningsCd = @EarningsCdnew))
    ROLLBACK TRAN;   
THROW 60000, 'Cannot process invalid EarningsCd', 1 ;
```

Notice that I've unindented the `THROW`; that because it's not part of the `IF`. When you don't use a `BEGIN` and `END` with an `IF`, *only* the next line is executed if the `IF` resolves to `TRUE`. That doesn't, however, mean that adding a `BEGIN` and `END` if the correct solution. You shouldn't be performing a `ROLLBACK` in a `TRIGGER`; that causes a further error in the calling SQL. Instead just put the `THROW` in your `IF` and increase the severity to `10`:

```sql
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT EarningsCd 
               FROM ptref.EarningDecode 
               WHERE EarningsCd = @EarningsCdnew))
    THROW 60000, 'Cannot process invalid EarningsCd', 10;
```

The thing is, however, is that all of these statements are a completely moot point. What you should *really* be doing here is using a foreign key constraint. The problem, however, is you can't do that with your current design. On your table `ptref.EarningDecode` you have defined the columns (plural) `CountryGroupingCd` and `EarningsCd` as your `PRIMARY KEY`, however, in your table `rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime` you are missing the column `CountryGroupingCd`, and you don't *say* you have a `UNIQUE INDEX` (or `CONSTRAINT`) on the column `EarningsCd` in the other table. As such you can't create a Foreign Key Constraint pointing back to `ptref.EarningDecode`.

To make matters "worse" `rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime` has a Primary Key made up of 5 columns; this is most certainly a design flaw. Primary Keys are normally made up of 1 column, and perhaps 2 in rare circumstances. They *are* occasions when there might be more, but these are normally bridge tables that are used for many to many relationships between multiple tables. As such the only columns in the table are the Primary Key columns and nothing else; this is clearly not the case here.

This likely means one of a few things:

1. You are using multiple columns to maintain uniqueness when you should have multiple tables
2. The other columns should not be part of the Primary Key, but the PK should be `NONCLUSTERED` and the columns (including the PK) should be in a `CLUSTERED INDEX` (I doubt this for `rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime`).
3. The PK is simply defined wrong, and the other columns should just not be part of it, or a `CLUSTERED INDEX`.
4. The PK should be a completely separate column and a `UNIQUE INDEX`/`UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` should be created on the columns you have defined as the PK.

Lookg at the table `ptref.EarningDecode` I would *guess* that this should be several tables, 2 with separate PKs for the `Earning` and `CountGroup` and then a 3rd which has Foreign Key constraints to both and it's own separate Primary Key Constraint. For `AdditionalPaymentsRealTime` I suspect that the PK definition is simply wrong and that either point 3 or 4 apply.

As we have no sample data, it's impossible to know which is the *right* answer here, but I would strongly expect one of them is. Once you fix the design, you can easily make a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` from your table `rt.AdditionalPaymentsRealTime` to the newly defined `ptref.EarningDecode` with it's new single column Primary Key.